# Successively capturing data in nested pages with Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, meta

I'm trying to scrape a fairly straightforward website with a Scrapy BaseSpider since I know in advance where all of the links that I want to crawl are.

The basic layout of the site to be crawled is

1. List of States
2. List of Counties within a State
3. List of agencies within a County
4. Information about a single agency

I can successfully navigate and get data at all 4 levels, however, my county field is not being populated correctly. For a given agency, instead of the actual county it is in, I get the last county in the State the agency is located in.

Example:

- OH - **County #3** - Agency #1  (should be **County #1**)
- OH - **County #3** - Agency #2  (should be **County #2**)
- OH - **County #3** - Agency #3  (correct)

Can't seem to figure out something that I think is relatively simple.

Here's the code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from agencyspider.items import AgencyItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class BasicspiderSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "basicSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["usacops.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.usacops.com/',
        ]

    items = {}

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        states = sel.xpath('//comment()[.=" Begin State Names "]/following::table[1]/tr/td/a')
        for s in states:
            item = AgencyItem()
            state = s.xpath('text()').extract()[0]
            url = s.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
            item['state'] = state
            item['stateUrl']= url
            yield Request(url=url,callback=self.parse_counties,meta={'item':item})


    def parse_counties(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        counties = sel.xpath('//comment()[.=" Begin Counties "]/following::table[1]/tr/td/font/a | //comment()[.=" Begin Counties "]/following::table[1]/tr/td/a')
        for c in counties:
            item = response.request.meta["item"]
            county = c.xpath('text()').extract()[0]
            countyUrl = c.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
            url = item["stateUrl"] + countyUrl
            item["county"]=county
            item["countyUrl"]=url
            yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_agencies,meta={'item':item})

    def parse_agencies(self,response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        agencies = sel.xpath('//table[9]/tr/td/table[2]/tr/td/font/a | //table[9]/tr/td/table[2]/tr/td/a')
        for a in agencies:
            item = response.request.meta["item"]
            agency = a.xpath('text()').extract()[0]
            agencyUrl = a.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
            url =  item["stateUrl"] + agencyUrl
            item["agency"] = agency
            item["agencyUrl"] = url 
            yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_agencyinfo,meta={'item':item})

    def parse_agencyinfo(self,response):
        sel = Selector(response)        
        item = response.request.meta["item"]
        item["agency"]= ' '.join(sel.xpath('//comment()[.=" Begin center section "]/following::table/tr/td/strong/font[1]/text()').extract())
        item["admintype"]= ' '.join(sel.xpath('//comment()[.=" Begin center section "]/following::table/tr/td/strong/font[2]/text()').extract())
        item["adminhead"]= ' '.join(sel.xpath('//comment()[.=" Begin center section "]/following::table/tr/td/strong/font[3]/text()[1]').extract())
        item["address"]= ' '.join(sel.xpath('//comment()[.=" Begin center section "]/following::table/tr/td/strong/font[3]/text()[position()>1]').extract())
        return item
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey so the problem is every time you assign `item = response.request.meta["item"]` your referencing and assigning the same item over and over again.

Fortunately its an easy fix! Just wrap `response.request.meta["item"]` with `AgencyItem(response.request.meta["item"])` to create a [copy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.20/topics/items.html#other-common-tasks) of the state item for each county.

Also don't forget to do the same in other callbacks or else you'll have the problem with other fields. Hope that helps!

Comment: That worked! For some reason I thought that that the request for new URLs would create a new scope for me instead of re-using the same objects.  Thank you!  I can pry myself away from the screen.  Wife and kids are happier.